# Prepopulating form from backend and posting in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, post

I have a question how can I post from two entities. Let says I have I created categories post now I want to use the categories post as a drop down and then post products by pulling the categories from my database in angular 2/4. I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance. Please see below the problem I have

my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response}  from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()

export class myService {

 addProduct(prod){



 const body = JSON.stringify(prod);

 const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});


 let Url= "https://localhost/v1/products";

 return this.http.post(Url, body, {headers: headers}).map(res=>res.json())



}


addCat(cat){ 

  const body = JSON.stringify(cat);

 const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});


let catUrl= "https://localhost/v1/cat";

 return this.http.post(Url, body, {headers: headers}).map(res=>res.json())


}

 getCat(){
     this.http.get(catUrl).map(res => res.json())
 }
}
```

below is the component where I am trying to create the product by pre-populating some fields from the categories which have an id, category type as fields
   product component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MyService} from '../myservice'; 

 @Component({


 selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  cat: any = [];
   proName: any;
   proPrice: any;

  constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){

 this.cat =   this.myService.getCat().subscribe(rescat => this.cat = rescat)
  }

  addProduct(){
       let produc ={
               name: this.proName,
               price: this.proPrice,
               catType: this.cat.name,
               catId : this.cat.id 



           }


       this.myService.addProduct(produc).subscribe(data => 
       console.log(data))
  }

}
```

html content is this

```
   <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" (ngSubmit)="addProduct()">
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  Identification" 
      [(ngModel)]="proName" name="proName"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  
     [(ngModel)]="proPrice" name="proPrice">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group"   >
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cat.name" 
  [(ngModel)]="cat.name " >
  </div>
```

I am not sure how to include the category within the product creation any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is really very broad and lacks any specific detail that would be helpful in answering the question.  See [ask], specifically the section titled **"Help others reproduce the problem"**

Comment: where exactly is the problem? Could you please elaborate on that? :)

Comment: the problem it is not creating the product, i am not sure what I am missing with the categories

Comment: @amad4biz *not creating product* is not really helpful either? Is nothing happening? Are you getting no values, or just some values? Where do you establish this? Could you create a plunker that shows what the problem is?